# Content goes behind soft navigation bar for api 21 and up

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-view, windowinsets

Have upgraded app to use Material Design - **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar**, **Toolbar** instead of **ActionBar** etc..

And have a problem.
Bottom content become to be hidden under soft NavigationBar (see picture below) on devices with APi >= 21

Have found solution to fix this:

in **values-v21/styles.xml**

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/green</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
</styles>
```

if option `<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>` - bottom content is visible, but **statusbar** become completely black. I cant change color to **colorPrimaryDark** (green in my case)

if option `<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>` - bottom content is invisible, and **statusbar** is green, as expected.

I want to have statusbar colored(green) and visible bottom content..
Probably, issue is with **toolbar**. Is it pushes content down?

Any suggestions?

`<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>`

[image]

`<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>`

[image]

UPDATE:

As suggested @azizbekian, I've replaced container for fragmets to CoordinatorLayout(before FrameLayout) and applied `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`
In this case bottom panel is visible, but not at the bottom..
Goal is to keep buttons athe bottom...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <!-- The main content view -->
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:id="@+id/content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

layout of the screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <FocusableScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/order_editor_layout"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                layout="@layout/o_e_content" 
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FocusableScrollView>
    <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/oe_bottom_pane"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is result:

[image]

**UPDATE#2**

Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <!-- The main content view -->
        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Replaced `LinearLayour` with `CoordinatorLayout` as root for activity.
 As root element for content I've keep `FrameLayout`.
Applied `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to `CoordinatorLayout`.
This way, all content was slightly moved up and part of placed below the toolbar(you can see on image below - top elements are circle with + and - symbold. But on previous images there are text on the top.) Regarding bottom elements (buttons panel) - still placed below navigation bar but also slightly moved up. I've marked `android:background="@color/red"` to easier recognize position of this panel.

Seems, we are on the right way. All we need - to resolve problem - why content moved below the toolbar.. If tolbar will be top ui elemnt, buttons will be visible..

[image]

Comment: write this property in your layout.xml parent layout.
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

Comment: Have tried this approach, but it was not helped me.. Now, in some places bottom content is visible, in some - not. ANd button are placed not at the bottom of the screen. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Apply `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your root view.

See [this post](https://medium.com/@azizbekian/windowinsets-24e241d4afb9) for detailed explanation.

Comment: at the top I have an Activity. With FrameLayout as container for fragments:
 <!-- The main content view -->
        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Acording to your post - all I need - is to change FrameLayout to some materialish layout like CoordinatorLayout and apply fitsSystemWindows option.. I'm right?

Comment: Yes, and `android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds` set to `true`.

Comment: I'm not sure that CoordinatorLayout is good practice to use as a container for fragments. Mostly it is FrameLayout..

Comment: It depends on your use case.

Comment: Have replaced container layout with Coordinator. Bottom buttons are visible, but not at the bottom of the screen.. Is it a CoordinatorLayout feature? I've added xml in question. Could you please check?

Comment: @vsvydenko, remove `LinearLayout`. Make `CoordinatorLayout` the root of your view hierarchy. Currently, `fitsSystemWindows` won't take effect, because as mentioned in the post `LinearLayout` won't dispatch system inset to `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: Updated my question. Added CoordinatorLayout as top element. Some of my content moved below the toolbar. Seems we need to fix this, and bottom buttons panel will be visible. Do you have any thoughts regarding this?

Comment: Post your project at github, I'll have a look.

Comment: I am also suffering from this problem, did you manage to figure it out @vsvydenko?